# Append a React component in another on button click

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a big component `<User>` and a small one `<Task>` and want to give a big component a button and on click on it append the component `<Task>` to the `<User>`

### User.jsx

```
<div>
  <Task />
  <button onClick={`Function here to append a new Task component`}>
    New Task
  </button>
</div>
```

### Task.jsx

```
<div>
  This is New task
</div>
```

Comment: Could you include both your `User` and `Task` component code, and show what you have tried so far?

Comment: I don't know how to do this in reactjs

Comment: write the component here or in https://jsfiddle.net/
it will help us help you

Comment: @ZeyadEtman check this answer, you will get a basic idea about conditional rendering of the component [**Link**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47978993/how-to-render-element-on-click-of-button-reactjs/47979053#47979053), in case you want to render multiple component, maintain a count (initial value=0) in state variable and use loop to render that many elements.

Comment: You should adapt a different mindset when working with React. React allows you to describe your UIs declaratively. Think about it as "given this data, this it what my UI look like". So instead of trying to "append a new Task component", you'd update the data the UI is based on, which then would render as many Task components as needed.

Comment: Linked: https://stackoverflow.com/q/57455821/104380

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could do something like the following.

```js
const User = () => {
  return <p>User</p>
}

class App extends React.Component {

  state = {
    users: []
  }

  addUser = () => {
    this.setState({
      users: [...this.state.users, <User />]
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.addUser}>Add User</button>
        {this.state.users}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

There is a code sandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/qj1n3yrmj).

Comment: storing ui elements in state variable is really a bad idea, better to maintain a count and render that many elements using loop.

Comment: @MayankShukla What is the reason for this?

Comment: Another good example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35906206/6200607 It uses a count to render.

Answer (score 19):

You should let React render everything, and your job is only to tell React what to render and, in your case, how many times. For that, a `counter` can be used to track how many dynamically-added should be "injected" inside the `<Example>` component.

A mindshift is needed here, since in your example you are coming from a place where you think that the click handler itself should modify the DOM, and in React that is an antipattern.

Instead, you should work with **state**, and that means the click handler should update the state of the host component and that will trigger a re-render (this is how React works) and in the next render cycle, your added component will be rendered as many times as the counter value, because that counter change is what triggered the re-rendering.

In React, the props & state are the way to trigger re-render and any DOM modification should be done by changing the internal component's state, or by sending different props, from the parent component.

---

In the below example I *do not* use **Classes**, but use **[Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html)** instead, because I've stopped using *class* altogether once hooks were released, because I think it's cleaner:

```js
const {useState, Fragment} = React

// The added element component
const AddedElement = () => <p><input placeholder='text box' /></p>

// The parent component
const App = () => {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0) // Name it however you wish

  return <Fragment>
    <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>Click me</button>
    { [...Array(count)].map((_, i) => <AddedElement key={i} />) }
  </Fragment>
}

// Render 
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("react"))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.11.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.11.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

If you are interested in how to **repeatedly render** the same component, I've written an answer about this in this question: [How can I render repeating React elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51359938/104380)

Comment: Use memos in react

Comment: How will you keep track of the value of each new element?

Comment: @Faahmed - that is the easiest part actually. Every app has its own Form-state system. I cannot give a solution that can apply for all and not even 10% I would guess, but, since you have an index for each input, you can store the value (per field) in another key/value object state

Answer (score 1):

```js
const Task = (props) => {
  return (
    <li>{props.value}</li>
  )
}

class TaskForm extends React.Component {
  state = { 
    value : ''
  };
  
  handleChange = (e) => {
    const { value } = e.target;
    this.setState(_ => ({
      value
    }));
  }
  
  handleAdd = (e) => {
    const { value } = this.state;
    if (value === '') { return; }
    this.props.onNewTask(value);
    this.setState(_ => ({
      value : ''
    }))
  }
  
  render () {
    const { value } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <input 
          value={value} 
          onChange={this.handleChange}
        />
        <button onClick={this.handleAdd}>Add</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

class User extends React.Component {
  state = {
    tasks : []
  }
  
  handleNewTask = (task) => {
    this.setState(state => ({
      ...state,
      tasks : [
        ...state.tasks,
        task
      ]
    }))
  }
  
  renderTasks () {
    const tasks = this.state.tasks.map(t => (
            <Task key={t} value={t} />
    ));
    return (
      <ul>
        {tasks}
      </ul>
    )
  }
  
  render () {
    return (
      <div>
        <TaskForm onNewTask={this.handleNewTask}/>
        {this.renderTasks()}
      </div>
    )
  }
}


ReactDOM.render(<User/>, document.querySelector('#app'));
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.4.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.4.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <div id="app"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";

const Element = () => {
  return (
    <div style={{ marginTop: "10px" }}>
      <input type="file" />
      <select id="cars" name="carlist" form="carform">
        <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
        <option value="saab">Saab</option>
        <option value="opel">Opel</option>
        <option value="audi">Audi</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  );
};

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    elements: [
      <div style={{ marginTop: "10px" }}>
        <input type="file" />
        <select id="cars" name="carlist" form="carform">
          <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
          <option value="saab">Saab</option>
          <option value="opel">Opel</option>
          <option value="audi">Audi</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    ]
  };

  addUser = () => {
    this.setState({
      elements: [...this.state.elements, <Element />]
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h3>Append a React component in another on button click</h3>
        {this.state.elements}

        <button onClick={this.addUser} style={{ marginTop: "10px" }}>
          Add User
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```